# ubuntu ноут + 2 монитора

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Дано  ноут  с 2 выходами vga, display port+ ( переходник на vga )
OS ubuntu

ubuntu  при подключений 2 мониторов оба теряют сигнал.
мониторы разные

```
вывод: xrandr     
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x 
axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
1366x768      60.00*+
1360x768      59.96  
1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
1024x768      60.00  
1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.32    56.25  
864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
640x480       59.94  
720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
680x384       60.00  
640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080     60.00 +
1680x1050     59.95  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      60.00  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x800      59.81  
1152x864      75.00  
1280x720      60.00  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
640x480       75.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1366x768      59.79 +
1280x720      60.00  
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
832x624       74.55  
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

отключаю 1 монитор все ок  монитор определяется  меня местами тоже все ок.

как решить данный вопрос

Comment: видеокарта какая? У меня на атоме отрубалось все если поле вывода мониторов превышало 2048*2048 по ширине или высоте. также встречал 4096*4096

Comment: попробуй пасположить мониторы чтоб не было больше 4096 по ширине, чтоб проверить гипотезу

Comment: lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте при включенных обоих мониторах на ноутбуке попереключать режимы вывода на экран. У меня это F10 клавиша + Fn.

Comment: seper+p   решил вопрос но пришлось  отключить  дисплей ноута.   всем спасибо

Comment: @dev707 похоже всетаки в размер фреймбуфера не влезает

Comment: да  на винде такаяже  фигня

Comment: да, проблема аппаратная

Answer (score 0):

Видеокарта не поддерживает размер экрана больше 4096х4096.

Помогло отключение экрана ноутбука.

Также поможет расположение экранов квадратом.